# Eclipse Angular IDE project creation fails and has wrong node version

Tags: eclipse, angular

I'm on a mac. I just installed Angular IDE (eclipse) and when I try to create a new Angular project it fails. I can run the same commands from the terminal and it works. I'm using node 8.9.1 and npm 5.5.1 outside the IDE, but can't find where to tell the plugin to use that version.

```
Node.js version:    v9.1.0
NPM version:        5.5.1
npm install @angular/cli@1.4.9
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.1.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js.
Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.
/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node[4666]: ../src/node_zlib.cc:437:static void node::(anonymous namespace)::ZCtx::Init(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 2: node::(anonymous namespace)::DomainEnter(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Object>) [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 3: node::(anonymous namespace)::ZCtx::Init(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/nodejs/9.1.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x337a5df842fd
/Users/bobsmith/.webclipse/npm/5.5.1/bin/npm: line 14:  4666 Abort trap: 6           node "$basedir/../bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with [Angular Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse) instead of Angular IDE?

Comment: @howlger Yes, it seems that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to execute outside the IDE the line "npm install @angular/cli@1.4.9", later in the IDE, you need to create the project with the same versions for node, npm, en angular cli that you have installed in your machine.